# Como utilizar o Font Awesome?

Tags: css

Estou utilizando um template que utiliza ícones do  Font Awesome, até aí tudo bem! Mas quando quero mudar o ícone, sigo as instruções da documentação e não dá certo!

Por exemplo, o código do template é esse:

```
<li class="wow fadeInRight">
   <i class="icon-lock">
</li>
```

Se eu quiser por exemplo, mudar para o ícone do Facebook, altero `<i class="icon-lock">` para `<i class="fa fa-heart">` e fui ver o CSS e está assim:

```
.icon-lock:before {
  content: "\e62a";
}
```

O que significa esse CSS? O que é `"\e62a"` ???

Me ajudem, por favor !!!

Answer (score 4):

`\e62a` é o código (unicode) correspondente a um icone nessa fonte. Ou seja, a fonte tem uma tabela onde cada código desses corresponde a um icon.

Alguns desses códigos/icons podem ser vistos aqui: http://astronautweb.co/snippet/font-awesome/

Em relação ao teu código específico tens de reproduzir o erro para perceber-mos melhor o problema. [Segundo a documentação](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icon/heart/) devias ter um unicode `f004`.

Não te esqueças de juntar:

```
.fa-heart:before {
  content: "\xxxx"; /* <- aqui colocas o teu unicode */
}
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/u36nf717/

Se ainda tiveres problemas faz um jsFiddle que reproduza o problema.

Comment: +1. Eu até proponho que, depois de passar da fase de protótipo, era ideal tirar os `<i ...></i>` e colocar esses `::before` diretamente nos estilos apropriados — o ícone é, num certo sentido, parte decorativa da página, e não faz sentido poluir o HTML com eles.

Answer (score 1):

Muito cuidado com uma coisa: a versão 4 do FontAwesome usa esses estilos tipo `"fa fa-heart"` que você descreveu. Se o código que você pegou pra mexer usa ainda a versão 3 (que é o que parece, pelo `"icon-lock"`), você tem que consultar os nomes na [lista completa de ícones](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/3.2.1/icons/). Nesse caso, você vai sempre colocar só uma classe no HTML, no caso `class="icon-heart"`.